# Jquery filtering by multiple parameters issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, leaflet

The goal of my app located below is scenario based. If I click on Korean in the categories and I want to see all with a 4 star rating the results should simplify based on that query.

Right now I have an issue where I can filter by either star rating or category but not both at the same time. When I filter by both all of the results disappear.

Example can be found here (a lot of stuff is not working fyi): https://final-630-bthukxpnol.now.sh/

My question is why is this happening? Is there a different way to filter that I am not using?

Please ask for me to provide more info if anything is unclear.

JS:

```
$('#star-filter, #cat-filter').delegate('input[type=checkbox]', 'change', function() {
        // $('input.star').not(this).prop('checked', false);  
        var $list = $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');  
        if ($checked.length) {                          
            var sel = '';
            var catsel = '';
            var selector = '';

            $($checked).each(function(index, element){
                sel += "[data-staralt~='" + element.name + "']";  
                catsel += "[data-cat~='" + element.value + "']"; 
                selector += "[data-star~='" + element.value + "']";   
            });                        
            $list.hide();
            $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle').filter(sel).show();
            $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle').filter(catsel).show(); 
            $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle').filter(selector).show();

        }
        else {
            $list.show();
        }
    });
```

I am using D3.js and leaflet.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why no matches remain when you check both is that you generate filters that contain contradictory conditions. For instance, it would generate 3 selectors like this:

```
[data-staralt~='4.5'][data-staralt~='category']
[data-cat~='4'][data-cat~='Ramen']
[data-star~='4'][data-star~='Ramen']
```

Each one is saying that the attribute should contain *both* words at the same time. This is not what you were after. Instead, I think you want to perform this logic (in pseudo language):

```
([data-staralt~='4.5'] or [data-cat~='4'] or [data-star~='4']) AND
([data-staralt~='category'] or [data-cat~='Ramen'] or [data-star~='Ramen'])
```

This you can achieve with the following code. Side note: don't use the deprecated `delegate` jQuery method, but the `on` method (which has its first two parameters reversed):

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    var $list = $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle'),
        $checked = $('input:checked');  
    if ($checked.length) {                          
        $list.hide();
        $($checked).each(function(index, element){
            // Reduce list to what matches one of the three filters.
            // The comma in the selector works as a logical OR:
            $list = $list.filter("[data-staralt~='" + element.name + "'],[data-cat~='" + element.value + "'],[data-star~='" + element.value + "']");
        });
    }
    // Show what remains in list:
    $list.show();
});
```

### Appendix

After our conversion, I have the impression you need the following logic:

```
([data-staralt~='4.5'] or [data-staralt~='3.5']) and 
([data-cat~='4'] or [data-cat~='3']) and 
([data-star~='4'] and [data-star~='3])
```

I also came to understand the reason for `staralt`, i.e. to include 3.5 also when 3 is selected. But this you can do with the `^=` comparison. So I would do that instead of the extra `name` attribute check.

So that leads to the following code:

```
function createFilter(type) { // Helper function
    var filter = [];
    $("#" + type + '-filter input:checked').each(function(index, element) {
        filter.push("[data-" + type + "^='" + element.value + "']"); // Use ^= to match the start of the actual value
    });
    return filter.join(",") || "*"; // Asterisk means: no filter at all
}

$(document).on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function() {
    $('.leaflet-zoom-animated > g > circle')
        .hide()
        .filter(createFilter("star")) // Any of the checked star selections, AND
        .filter(createFilter("review")) // Any of the review selections, AND
        .filter(createFilter("cat")) // Any of the cat selections
        .show(); // Show the matches of the above filter
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the time you put in. This worked perfectly and your explanation is very easy to understand. The star values are not working as expected. Is there a way to create an `AND` logic for each star value?

For example:
`([data-staralt~='4.5'] and [data-cat~='4'] and [data-star~='4']) and ([data-staralt~='3.5'] and [data-cat~='3'] and [data-star~='3]) AND...`

So that you can have both 3 star and 4 star results active?

Comment: But that would not give any results? I mean the first and 4th condition will never be true for the same circle, right? And that is what a logical AND requires.

Comment: Right but what if I were the user and only wanted to see 3 and 4 star rated restaurants in the area before I even filter for category?

Comment: Do you maybe mean `([data-staralt~='4.5'] or [data-staralt~='3.5']) and ([data-cat~='4'] or [data-cat~='3']) and ([data-star~='4'] and [data-star~='3])`?

Comment: I think? I am still trying to understand the logic. Just so that when I click 3 and 4 star all restaurants with both values show

Comment: What is the function of alt-star compared to star? They seem to duplicate the same functionality?

Comment: I also don't understand why the name of the 5-star checkbox is "check"? I think you should first simplify this application so we can focus on one problem at the time. Usually the best way to do that is to create a JS fiddle.

Comment: I needed to find a way to display both 3 and 3.5 star ratings together. The way I set it up it would only allow me to show whole numbers or numbers with a decimal value and not both. So, I matched the input checkbox value and alt-star value directly with json data values. This way I could show both, it was a hack to show all restaurants 4 and 4.5 ratings.

Comment: I kept trying to create a fiddle and a codepen but the points would not render. That's why I resorted to ZEIT app

Comment: But with a `~=` selector you check whether the string occurs anywhere, so if you do `~=4` you also match `4.5`. Just be careful with matching `~=5`, because that would *also* match `1.5`, `2.5`... etc. So I would suggest to require that the match is at the *start*. So then `^=4` will still match `4.5`, but `^=5` will not match `3.5`.

Comment: Thank you for having accepted the answer already. I have now added a solution that corresponds to what I understand from our conversation here.